# docker-compose build and docker build giving different results

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, composer-php

I have created a simple Dockerfile to install apache with PHP and then install packages from composer.json.

```
FROM php:7-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY ./src/html/ .
COPY composer.json .

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y unzip

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN composer update
```

When I run `docker build -t my-web-server .` followed by `docker run -p 8080:80 my-web-server`, everything works fine and the packages install.

But when I use a docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  ecp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
```

and perform `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose up` The packages do not install and I just index.php is taken across to the container

my current file structure:

```
src
 |-- html
     |-- index.php
composer.json
docker-compose.yaml
Dockerfile
```

When `docker-compose` is building the image all the console outputs are identical to that of `docker build`

Comment: Run `apt` first, then `composer` (you'll have to copy its files for that), then copy your code. Point is, every change to your HTML will make you repeat the steps after that in your Dockerfile, even if their results don't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two approaches are not identical. You are using volumes in your docker compose, and not in your docker call. Your problem lies there.

More specifically, notice that in your docker compose you are mounting your host's `./src` to your container's `./var/www` - which is not the giving you the correct structure, since you "shadow" the container's folder that contains your `composer.json` (which was copied to the container at build time).

To avoid such confusion, I suggest that if you want to mount a volume with your compose (which is a good idea for development), then your `docker-compose.yml` file should mount the exact same volumes as the `COPY` commands in your `Dockerfile`. For example:

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./src/html:/var/www/html
  - ./composer.json:/var/www/html/composer.json
```

Alternatively, remove the `volumes` directive from your `docker-compose.yml`.

Note that it can be a cause for additional problems and confusion to have a file (in your case `composer.json`) copied to a folder in the container, while having the same folder also copied to the container as is. It is best to have the structure on the container mimic the one on the host as closely as possible.

Comment: Cool. Just notice that with this, you will end up with a copy of `composer.json` in your hosts's `src/html` folder - which may or may not be desired.

Comment: I also noticed, there will still be an issue where the vendor folder would be created in /html, and then once you do docker-compse up the volume will override that folder and delete the vendor folder if its not present on the external machine, so I defined a volume called vendor and pointed it to /var/www/html/vendor so that it would not be overriden in a build/up. But still does not effect portability. If that makes sense. And the ./composer volume is not required, as vendor is created in the dockerbuild and it also stops that duplicate issue. But it would require a rebuild every dep change.

Comment: Yes. In my PHP websites, I have the root directory contain the `Dockerfile`, the `composer.json` and all the PHP files (starting with `index.php`) so my `Dockerfile` is just doing `COPY . .` and then it is easy to mount and work with.